# How to connect to Mongodb atlas cluster with http or https uri

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am connecting to Mongodb Atlas cluster with the standard connection string:

```
mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-enkbb.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

However, my organization is blocking connection to any uri except http or https. So mongodb or mongodb+srv prefixes are blocked and getting connection timeout error. Is it possible to connect using http or https uri version of it?. I have tried by creating the api keys for access but still unable to do it.

Comment: not sure if there is a http/https thing to connect, how are you connecting to mongoDB ?

Comment: I am able to connect to locally hosted mongodb with mongodb://localhost:27017/test but unable to do so with mongo atlas cluster. I have whitelisted 0.0.0.0/0 ip so that it can be publicly accesed

Comment: Ok, are you using any driver or thru mongo-shell ?

Comment: I am using mongoose. Not using mongo-shell

Comment: Unfortunately it's currently not possible. Alternatively, you probably can create a REST API endpoint using [MongoDB Stitch](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/stitch).

Comment: Came across this, on how to interact with MongoDB Atlas using Stitch, may help you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBEzGFpAnhY